# PHP Use Wildcard with DOMDocument

Tags: php

I want to search a url to see if it has a jquery.min.js I do not know or need to know what is the path , version number, or number of instances...just if it exists anywhere on the web page. Could be in a link or script tag. Tried in script tag just to see if I can get it working.

Is it possible to modify the $node line below to do that with a wildcard?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xp->query( '//script[@src="jquery.min.js"]')->item( 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `contains` XPath function:

```
$node = $xp->query('//script[contains(@src,"jquery.min.js")]')->item(0);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  When I echo $node returns nothing. If I change it to: $node = $xp->query( '//script[@src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"]')->item( 0); it returns nothing also.