# Get elements by tag name starting with string in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to get all tag elements in PHP that are starting with a certain string, similar to this:

```php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $content );
    $domPre = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'spx-' );
    $length = $domPre->length;

    return json_encode( $length );
```

Of course, the above is not working. Any pointers to the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669976/php-use-wildcard-with-domdocument

Comment: Tried it, but just return null

Comment: Please show a small example of your HTML. Without that, we can't reproduce that and don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Using XPath - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337341/xpath-to-select-nodes-starting-with-a-certain-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions, this has worked for me:

```php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $content );
    $xp    = new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $array = [];

    foreach ( $xp->query( "//*[contains(local-name(),'spx')]" ) as $node ) {
        array_push( $array, $dom->saveXML( $node ), "\n" );
    }

    return json_encode( count( $array ) );
```

Comment: `starts-with` would be better

Comment: xpath-> query returns a nodeList object. With $nodeList-> length you get the number of elements.
To get an array of DOMElements you can just use iterator_to_array ($nodeList).